# Password Sanitisation on PHP LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

My goal is to create a website (PHP) which must authenticate to our active directory with LDAP.

I am looking at making use of the code from [this site](https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/using-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php) however one thing I noticed is that there is no sanitisation on the passwords.

Is there a need to sanitise the username and password or is that done by the LDAP server? If there is, how would I go about doing this but still allow special characters? (ie <>=?|! could be in user passwords)

Comment: *When building LDAP queries in application code, you MUST escape any untrusted data that is added to any LDAP query*.. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/LDAP_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: The password needs to be passed as-is to `ldap_bind`. Values entered into ldap-search etc need to be escaped using `ldap_escape`. But the password in `ldap_bind` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: What have you tried so far?